# Rebuilding of xDB index stuck after 19-30 documents after scaling up Azure Search

Tags: xdb, indexing, azure-search

We have an issue with Sitecore xDB index in Azure Search on Sitecore 9.1.1.

- Recently we tried to rebuild xDB index. It started without any issues but after indexing 3 million documents we ran out of storage - 25GB was not enough to keep xDB index, secondary xDB index for rebuilding and default Sitecore indexes.
- We scaled up Azure Search by adding one more partition - now we have 50GB on 2 partitions.
- We restarted xc-search app service and started rebuilding of xDB index again.
  Secondary index was removed and recreated, logs in IndexWorker contain only standard message

```
[Information] Starting Xdb Indexer App Domain, Machine: DW1MDWK000006, InstanceName: ConnectIndexer_AppDomain 
[Information] AppInsightsPerformanceCounters Constructor, Instance:XConnectIndexer, Path: App_Data\Diagnostics, CounterFilePattern: *.json 
[Information] Done.
```

After 1 hour there was only 1 document in secondary index. Thanks to Dean and Anna I was able to find out that removing 'xdb-rebuild-status' document from primary xdb index allowed to finally get some xdb data into the index but it stops sometimes after 19, sometimes after 21 and sometimes after 30 documents.

I checked there is no throttling on Azure Search[image]

We increased the app service plan used by `xc-search` to it doesn't use more than 60% of RAM now and CPU around 20-30%.

We increased elastic pool so none of the shards DTU usage is in low percents as well.

In the meantime I found a setting in `sc.Xdb.Collection.IndexWriter.AzureSearch.xml` file:

```
<!-- Uncomment this setting if there is more than one replica, default value equals '0'.
 This setting compensates time necessary for copying indexed data among all Azure search 
 replicas.-->
<!--<DataReplicationTimeoutMilliseconds>2000</DataReplicationTimeoutMilliseconds>-->
```

I uncommented this setting and changed the value first to 5000 milliseconds and then even to 60000 milliseconds. Restarted `xc-search` app service. That hasn't helped. Still the highest value we reached is 30 documents.

I lowered `MaximumUpdateBatchSize`, `SplitRecordsThreshold` and `BatchSize` and increased timeouts. That made no difference.

No exceptions in `xc-search` logs despite changing serilog level to `Verbose`.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Do the logs in the indexing service show:  [Information] Rebuilding process. Stage: Starting. Total progress: 0.00%. Stage progress: 0.00%. to begin? If so does it get stuck at a certain percentage? or show something else?

Comment: Nothing more in the logs. We're on 9.1.1. We've never seen anything more in the logs, even before upscaling Azure Search when it indexed more than 3 million of documents. From what I can see in Sitecore documentation, monitoring was only added in 9.2.

Comment: Hmm sounds frustrating. Do azure web apps have event logs? Maybe try in powershell window: 1) Get-Eventlog -newest 20 application  2) (Get-Eventlog -index <ID of one you want> application).message

Comment: In event log I can only see messages from a week ago "Worker Process requested recycle due to 'Percent Slow Requests' limit.". Nothing from yesterday or today. No explanation why we cannot rebuild the xdb index